# Is a function growing faster than any computable function necessarily independent of ZFC?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory

Let $\mathrm{BB}:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be the Busy beaver function. Then we have the following.

> Let $T$ be a computable and arithmetically sound axiomatic theory.
> Then there exists a constant $n_T$ such that for all $n\geq n_T$, no
> statement of the form "$\mathrm{BB}(n)=k$" can be proved in $T$.

[Yedidia-Aaaronson](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.04343) have shown that $n_{\mathrm{ZFC}}\leq 8000$.

Does a similar statement hold for any function that grows faster than any computable function?

Comment: Assuming ZFC is arithmetically sound, yes, since otherwise by enumerating proofs in ZFC you could find a computable function bounding the given one.

Comment: @Wojowu do you mean an exhaustive search for the proof of each of these statements dictated by a pairing function?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. For every $n$ you look for all proofs of statements of the form "$BB(n)=k$" and output the resulting $k$ whenever you find a proof.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be a definable, monotone function such that $\mathrm{ZFC}$ proves infinitely many statements of the form $f(n) = k$. Then
there is a computable function $g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ with $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \ f(n) \leq g(n)$.

We compute $g$ as follows: On input $n$ we search through $\mathrm{ZFC}$-proofs until we find the first proof of some statement $f(m) = k$ for $m \geq n$, and then we output $k$. By assumption, this search will always terminate eventually. The monotonicity of $f$ ensures that $g$ is indeed dominating $f$.

By contraposition, we find that if a monotone definable function is not dominated by any computable function, $\mathrm{ZFC}$ proves only finitely many of its function values. And of course, there is nothing special about $\mathrm{ZFC}$ in here.

Comment: +1 But "nothing special about ZFC" may be an overstatement, depending on what "special" means. You've used that ZFC is computably axiomatizable (so that you can search through proofs) and arithmetically (or at least $\Sigma^0_1$) sound (so that you can trust statements of the form $f(m)=k$ when ZFC proves them). Maybe that's nothing special, but it seems worth mentioning.